# snap element outside a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

I have a div controlled by the cursor. I don't want this `<div>` go trough the gray box in the example. So the expected behavior is that you can use the blue box (cursor) everywhere, but the gray box. Snap effect similar to this - https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

here's my code:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
  console.log(e,e.pageX);
  var _cursorDiv = document.getElementById("tail");

  _cursorDiv.style.left = e.pageX+"px";
  _cursorDiv.style.top = e.pageY+"px";
});
```

and the sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3781/

Comment: Can you not just use jQuery?

Comment: I thought about it, and I tried some scripts with no success. Maybe I was using it wrongly. Do you know any library or plugin that helps me achieve this?